# While loop doesn't exit on false condition

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = null, surname = null;
    while (name != "A" && surname != "A")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
        name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
        surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Oops");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The loop works fine:

> Output1:
>
> Enter Name:
>
> John
>
> Enter Surname:
>
> Peter
>
> Enter Name:
>
> Jack
>
> Enter Surname:
>
> Andrew
>
> Output2: (Trying the break the loop at Point A)
>
> Enter Name:
>
> A  //loop didn't exit but went to the next statement
>
> Enter Surname:
>
> Peter
>
> Oops

When I try to break the loop at Point A, the loop doesn't exit, but goes to the next statement and then exits after point B

Question: Why doesn't it exit the loop at point and how can I make it exit at point A?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The loop condition will be checked exactly before entering the whole block of code not after every statement execution in code. You can add a condition to execute the second part or break out of the loop or force checking of loop condition.

**Breaking out of loop:**

```
while (name != "A" && surname != "A")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
    if (name == "A")
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
    surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
}
```

---

**Set a condition to execute rest of the code:**

```
while (name != "A" && surname != "A")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
    if (name != "A")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
        surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
    }
}
```

---

**Force to check the loop condition (code after continue will not execute):**

```
while (name != "A" && surname != "A")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
    if (name == "A")
        continue;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
    surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
}
```

Comment: They're just jealous that you can answer correctly while sleeping :)

Comment: Thanks, your first example will fit perfectly in my project.

Comment: I'd like to say, that though the first example provides the quickest most comprehensible solution, I would recommend against breaking the loop. The other two examples are better regarding long-term maintenance and readability and also are less likely to cause evasive bugs, should you decide to extend the loop at a later point in time.

Comment: @MrPaulch I'm on your side too!

Comment: Thanks for the input, will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
    if (name=="A")
    {
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
    surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
    if (surname=="A")
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition is checked only at the point, when all the code in the while loop has been processed. So everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your loop block.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
    name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
    if(name =="A")
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
    surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
    if(surname == "A")
        break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition will only be checked everytime the whole loop body got executed. If you want to break out of the loop you can use the [`break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/adbctzc4.aspx) statement

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = null, surname = null;
    while (surname != "A")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
        name = Console.ReadLine(); // Point A
        if (name == "A")
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname:");
        surname = Console.ReadLine(); // Point B
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Oops");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is going to go through all instructions before it rechecks the conditions of the loop.

You could make it exit at point A by using an if statement to check if name is "A" or "a" and then use the `break` command if it evaluates to true.

`if(name == "A" || name == "a")
    break;`